# Align cards in page using css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have made 4 cards using css, html and bootstrap 3. For some reason the first row doesn't have the 3 cards that i want but the second is, and they are not aligned perfectly when i zoom in(pixels difference).What can i do? You have an img down below of my 4 unaligned cards.
Here is the code :

HTML:

> ```
>        <div class="row">
>     <div class="card col-lg-4 col-md-6">
>       <div class="front">
>         <div>
>           <img class="girlimg" src="girl.jpg" alt="asdasda" />
>           <h2 class="activname">Guided hiking tours</h2>
>             <button class="activbutt" type="button" name="button">
>             SEE DETAILS
>             </button>
>
>
>         </div>
>         <div class="details">
>           <div class="duration">
>             <i class="fas fa-clock">Duration</i>
>           </div>
>           <div class="people">
>             <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><br />
>             <p>Max adults:10</p>
>           </div>
>           <div class="kids">
>             <i class="fas fa-child"></i><br />
>             <p>Max children:3</p>
>           </div>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
>   <br />
>
>   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 pop-up-2">
>     <div class="front">
>       <div>
>         <img class="girlimg" src="bike.jpg" alt="asdasda" />
>         <h2 class="activname">Rent a bike(4 hours)</h2>
>         <button class="activbutt" type="button" name="button">
>         SEE DETAILS
>         </button>
>       </div>
>       <div class="details">
>         <div class="duration">
>           <i class="fas fa-clock">Duration
>           <p>QUARTER DAY</p> </i>
>         </div>
>         <div class="people">
>           <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><br />
>           <p>Max adults:9</p>
>         </div>
>         <div class="kids">
>           <i class="fas fa-child"></i><br />
>           <p>Max children:0</p>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> <br>
> <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 pop-up-2">
>   <div class="front">
>     <div>
>       <img class="girlimg" src="climbing.jpg" alt="asdasda" />
>       <h2 class="activname">Climbing</h2>
>       <button class="activbutt" type="button" name="button">
>       SEE DETAILS
>       </button>
>     </div>
>     <div class="details">
>       <div class="duration">
>         <i class="fas fa-clock">Duration
>         <p>FULL DAY</p> </i>
>       </div>
>       <div class="people">
>         <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><br />
>         <p>Max adults:5</p>
>       </div>
>       <div class="kids">
>         <i class="fas fa-child"></i><br />
>         <p>Max children:1</p>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> </div>
> <br>
> <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 pop-up-2">
>   <div class="front">
>     <div>
>       <img class="girlimg" src="canoe.jpg" alt="asdasda" />
>       <h2 class="activname">Canoe</h2>
>       <button class="activbutt" type="button" name="button">
>       SEE DETAILS
>       </button>
>     </div>
>     <div class="details">
>       <div class="duration">
>         <i class="fas fa-clock">Duration
>         <p>QUARTER DAY</p> </i>
>       </div>
>       <div class="people">
>         <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><br />
>         <p>Max adults:6</p>
>       </div>
>       <div class="kids">
>         <i class="fas fa-child"></i><br />
>         <p>Max children:2</p>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> </div>
> ```

CSS:

[![>   .front{

> ```
>   margin-top: 30%;
>  width: 750px;
>  height:750px;
>  background-color: #F7F4F2;
>  align-items: baseline;
>  margin-left: 20%;
>  position: relative;
>  border-radius: 10%;
>  align-self: flex-start;
>  }
>
> .girlimg{
>   max-width: 500px;
>   min-height: 475px;
>   border-radius: 10%;
> }
>
> .details{
>   display: flex;
>         flex-direction: column;
>         justify-content: space-around;
>         justify-content: space-between;
>         position: absolute;
>         top:0;
>         right:0;
>         margin-left: %;
>         margin-top: 15%;
>         font-size: 30px;
> }
> .duration{
>   margin-bottom: 25%;
> }
> .people{
>   margin-bottom: 25%;
> }
> .kids{
>   margin-bottom: 25%;
> }
>
> .activname{
>   display: flex;
>   flex-direction: row;
>   margin-left: 7%;
>   margin-bottom: 5%;
>   font-size: 45px;
>
> }
>
> .activbutt{
>   background-color: #ffcc66;
>   border-radius: 2%;
>   display: flex;
>   margin-left: 20%;
>   font-size: 30px;
>   padding: 20px;
>   border: none;
>
> }
> ```

Image of my 4 cards:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kDFU.png

Comment: First when you zoom your browser it becomes tab or mobile view..so you need mention css in media query according to your requirement. Second, you have mentioned col-md-6 so it means it will show 50% of width in container. Third, You need to read & learn about how Bootstrap works...

Comment: remove <br> tag in HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

I removed unwanted margins from your code. Please check this snippet.

```css
.front {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #F7F4F2;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.details{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.activname{
    font-size: 20px;
}

.activbutt{
    background-color: #ffcc66;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="card col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="front">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <img class="girlimg" src="girl.jpg" alt="asdasda" />
                <h2 class="activname">Guided hiking tours</h2>
                <button class="activbutt" type="button" name="button">
                    SEE DETAILS
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="duration">
                    <i class="fas fa-clock">Duration</i>
                </div>
                <div class="people">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><br />
                    <p>Max adults:10</p>
                </div>
                <div class="kids">
                    <i class="fas fa-child"></i><br />
                    <p>Max children:3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 pop-up-2">
        <div class="front">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <img class="girlimg" src="bike.jpg" alt="asdasda" />
                <h2 class="activname">Rent a bike(4 hours)</h2>
                <button class="activbutt" type="button" name="button">
                    SEE DETAILS
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="duration">
                    <i class="fas fa-clock">Duration
                        <p>QUARTER DAY</p> </i>
                </div>
                <div class="people">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><br />
                    <p>Max adults:9</p>
                </div>
                <div class="kids">
                    <i class="fas fa-child"></i><br />
                    <p>Max children:0</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 pop-up-2">
        <div class="front">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <img class="girlimg" src="climbing.jpg" alt="asdasda" />
                <h2 class="activname">Climbing</h2>
                <button class="activbutt" type="button" name="button">
                    SEE DETAILS
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="duration">
                    <i class="fas fa-clock">Duration
                        <p>FULL DAY</p> </i>
                </div>
                <div class="people">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><br />
                    <p>Max adults:5</p>
                </div>
                <div class="kids">
                    <i class="fas fa-child"></i><br />
                    <p>Max children:1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 pop-up-2">
        <div class="front">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <img class="girlimg" src="canoe.jpg" alt="asdasda" />
                <h2 class="activname">Canoe</h2>
                <button class="activbutt" type="button" name="button">
                    SEE DETAILS
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="duration">
                    <i class="fas fa-clock">Duration
                        <p>QUARTER DAY</p> </i>
                </div>
                <div class="people">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><br />
                    <p>Max adults:6</p>
                </div>
                <div class="kids">
                    <i class="fas fa-child"></i><br />
                    <p>Max children:2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```